# Using client and server websockets in same python script

Tags: python, websocket, client, server

I am new to Python - and work on Slackware Linux with Python 3.4.3. I prefer simple no-dependency solutions within one single python script.

I am building a demonized server program (A) which I need to access through both a regular shell CLI and GUIs in my web browser: it serves various files, uses a corresponding database and updates a firefox tab through python's WEBBROWSER function. Currently, I access process (A) via the CLI or a threaded network socket. This all started to work in a localhost scenario with all processes running on one machine.

Now, it turns out that the WebSocket protocol would render my setup dramatically simpler and cut short on traditional flow protocols using Apache and complex frameworks as middlemen.

- 1st central question: How do I access daemon (A) with websockets from the CLI? I thought about firing up a non-daemon version of my server program, now called (B), and send a program call to its (A) counterpart via the WebSocket HTTP protocol. This would make process (B) a websocket CLIENT, and process (A) a websocket SERVER. Is such a communication at all possible today?
- 2nd question: Which is the best suited template solution for this scenario - that works with python 3.4.3 ?!  I started to play with Pithikos' very sleek python-websocket-server template (see https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server) but I am unable to use it as CLIENT (initiating the network call) to call its SERVER equivalent (receiving the call while residing in a daemonized process).

Answer (score 0):

Problem 'solved': I gave up on the zero-dependency zero-library idea :

```
pip install websockets
```

https://websockets.readthedocs.io

It works like a charm. The WebSocket server sits in the daemon process and receives and processes WebSocket client calls that come from the CLI processes and from the HTML GUIs.