# Websockets run client side and server side in 1 script with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, background, python-asyncio

I have 2 Python scripts running currently, 1 is client side script and 1 is server side script. They run perfectly ok. But, I want to combine both into 1 script to optimize data transfer. Below are the scripts.

Run as Client Side

```
async def init_wss_as_client():
    global SERVER
    try:
        async with websockets.connect(URI) as websocket:
            while True:
                response = await websocket.recv()
                ...
    finally:
        ...

SERVER = Server(DEVICE_ID)
asyncio.run(init_wss_as_client())
```

Run as Server Side

```
async def init_wss_as_server(websocket, path):
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            ...
    finally:
        ...

SESSION = Session(DEVICE_ID)
start_server = websockets.serve(init_wss_as_server, "0.0.0.0", 8443)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Below are my attempts.

1. Just combine 2 scripts

   ```
   SERVER = Server(DEVICE_ID)
   asyncio.run(init_wss_as_client())
   SESSION = Session(DEVICE_ID)
   start_server = websockets.serve(init_wss_as_server, "0.0.0.0", 8443)
   asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
   asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
   ```

   This only execute the first function
2. Merge 2 into 1 with `run_forever` by referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48822211/5737856).

   ```
   loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
   loop.run_until_complete(init_wss_as_client())
   loop.run_until_complete(websockets.serve(init_wss_as_server, "0.0.0.0", 8443))
   loop.run_forever()
   ```

   Only the first function executed too
3. I think 1 script can handle client and server side together if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007191/using-client-and-server-websockets-in-same-python-script) is correct.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To look at the [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) and [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)'s documentations, one should use `create_task` and one should use `run_until_complete`. Below is the code it works in my case.

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(init_wss_as_client())
loop.run_until_complete(websockets.serve(init_wss_as_server, "0.0.0.0", 8443))
loop.run_forever()
```